# strcpy problem with two dimension array in C

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I'm trying to copy a string to an array of strings using the `strcpy` function but it doesn't work!

Here is the code:

```
char *message[10] = { "Hello!000000000000", "Good Bye!", "1202", "hel", "beh", "cheshm" };
char *dst = "Copy";

strcpy(&(message[0]), "Copy");
printf("%s", message[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *two* problems:

1. `strcpy` expects a destination argument of type `char *`. But since `message[0]` is a `char *` then `&message[0]` is a pointer to that pointer which have the type `char **`. In other words, you pass the wrong pointer as the destination. That leads to *undefined behavior*.
2. The second problem happens when you fix the first, and that is you have to remember that literal strings are not modifiable. They are in effect read-only. And you try to copy a string into the literal string that `message[0]` is pointing to. Attempting to modify a literal string *also* leads to undefined behavior.

The solution to the second problem is to use an array of arrays of `char`:

```
char message[][256] = { ... };
```

The solution to the first problem is to simply pass `message[0]`:

```
strcpy(message[0], "Copy");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `strcpy` call is not a modifiable array of `char`, it is the array of `char*`, producing a type mismatch and unexpected behavior.

Modifying the code to `strcpy(message[0], "Copy")` would cause another problem as you would be trying to modify the string literal `"Hello!000000000000"` to which `message[0]` points.

If you just wish to modify the array element, just use a simple assignment to change the pointer:

```
char *message[10] = { "Hello!000000000000", "Good Bye!", "1202", "hel", "beh", "cheshm" };
char *dst = "Copy";

message[0] = "Copy";
printf("%s", message[0]);
```

Note that `message` is not a *3 dimensional* array. It is an array of pointers to `char`. You could define it as an actual 2D array with the same initializer and the contents would be modifiable:

```
char message[10][20] = { "Hello!000000000000", "Good Bye!", "1202", "hel", "beh", "cheshm" };
char *dst = "Copy";

strcpy(&(message[0]), "Copy");
printf("%s", message[0]);
```